# How to set db_block_size to 16384 in 12c during installation through dbca utility?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I need to set db_block_size to 16384 in my 64bit machine having 64bit windows 7 OS. I am creating a database through dbca utility. Please help.

Comment: *Why* do you *need* a 16k block size?

Answer (score 0):

The parameter can be edited if you have chosen Custom Template in step 3.

Oracle 12.2 DBCA
[image]

Comment: I am not getting this All Initialization Parameters button. I have 12cRelease 2 in my laptop.

Comment: Did you choose `Advanced Mode` in step 2?

Comment: Yes, I choose Advance Mode.

Answer (score 0):

But the database is already created? If it is, you can't change it by just altering the parameter value. This is one the parameters that is set at the time of the database creation and stays that way.
What you can do is create a new tablespace and set its block size to a different value. 
If indeed you're creating the database, you have to choose the custom template at the beginning of the installation in order to change that value.